# How to install Sharepoint

Tags: 2013, development, installation

I'm a beginner and I want to install SharePoint. I have Windows 7 and Microsoft Office 2013.

What I should do? Do I need Windows Server to install it?

Answer (score 1):

first , you need to decide on which version that you would like to have and then follow the msdn articles for latest 2013 version for hardware and software requirements.

[Reference msdn link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx)

you can also choose the version in the same article to get the understanding on pre-requisites.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to install Virtual Machine like VMWare WorkStation and then you have to install Microsoft windows server and Microsoft SQL after that SharePoint 2013.

Personally I referred this blog when I was installing my SharePoint. You can do the same and make sure you are meeting the system requirements for SP2013.

How to install it, please this check blog 
http://www.jeanpaulva.com/index.php/2014/01/23/installing-sharepoint-2013-on-virtual-machine/

Answer (score 0):

You can install the Sharepoint on windows 7, This is not supported but developer usually use for their own testing and learning. check this [Install SharePoint 2013 on Windows 7/8/8.1](http://www.disruptivei.com/Blogg/Inl%C3%A4gg/6/Install-SharePoint-2013-on-Windows-7-8-8-1)

I would highly recommend to install the VM on your windows 7 and install the SharePoint on it. You need the SQL server, Windows Server for the SharePoint, check the complete list of [pre-reuisite over here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx#section4).

[Building your SharePoint 2013 development machine on Windows Server 2012](https://cann0nf0dder.wordpress.com/2012/12/05/building-your-sharepoint-2013-development-machine-on-windows-server-2012-part-1-introduction/)

[How I can install SharePoint server 2013 on windows server 2008 inside a VM](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/67695/how-i-can-install-sharepoint-server-2013-on-windows-server-2008-inside-a-vm)